# how to bind dataset values in html table in C#? where my html table is written in txt file and it gets appended to mailbody

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

[html script of table appended to mail], I used streamreader to read txt file and created an new outlook application to draft email and then I wrote mail.HTMLBODY+=textstream.ToString(); whereas the dataset contains values from database. [image: ][1]]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing c# code in txt file you can use placeholders like `<<<place_holder_for_dscLinkKey>>>`. Then

```
string tmpBody = textstream.ToString().Replace(<placeholder>, <actualDBvalue>);
```

do above for all placeholders.

and finally

```
mail.HTMLBODY+=tmpBody ;
```